# diff two urls (i.e. html, css or js, etc.)

Tags: macos, diff

Anyone know of a tool to diff two files from a URL? I have different websites with different version of certain files (like js, css, html, etc.) and would like to compare both urls, like:

> http://domain.tld/js/x.js  vs http://domain.tld/js/y.js

Running OSX...

I now download (wget) the files needed, and then compare with FileMerge. But its kind of cumbersome. Some plugin would be preferred.

Answer (score 7):

I know you've said this is cumbersome, but it seems pretty simple...

```
diff <(curl -s http://example.com/foo) <(curl -s http://example.com/bar) --side-by-side
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below link, its an excellent tool to compare files online

http://www.diffnow.com/

Comment: thanks great find! But muy URL are on a LAN :( Will bookmark this one!

Comment: You can also try Beyond compare for Desktop application, its an excellent tool http://www.scootersoftware.com/

Comment: Beyond Compare does not work on OS X

Comment: Throwing [imnosy.com](http://imnosy.com/) into the mix. Tried out diffnow.com just now, and saw it doesn't display the rendered output.

Answer (score 1):

A tool to diff exactly two URLs and their GET parameters: [Compare two URLs by GET parameters](https://aleksey-yaremenko.ru/tools/url_compare/url_compare.html)

I use often the tool, more convenient than diffnow, because diffnow is good to compare two documents, not URLs.

Comment: This tool only compares the URLs themselves, not the contents; therefore it does *not* answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put together a small shell script which downloads both files via `curl` or `wget` and then compares them with `diff`, which is normally installed on every Mac OS X under `/usr/bin/diff`.

Comment: Thats how i do it now. It works, but its cumbersome. Some browser plugin would be cool, so you can open two pages and compare.